# Generic function using an interface

Tags: function, interface, generics, go

Since I've a similar function for 2 different data types:

```
func GetStatus(value uint8) (string) {...}
func GetStatus(name string) (string) {...}
```

I would want to use a way more simple like:

```
func GetStatus(value interface{}) (string) {...}
```

Is possible to create a generic function using an interface?
The data type could be checked using `reflect.Typeof(value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does what you want to do need the complexity and overhead of the [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)  package? Have you considered a simple [`switch`](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Switch_statements) statement `type` switch?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func GetStatus(value interface{}) string {
    var s string
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case uint8:
        v %= 85
        s = string(v + (' ' + 1))
    case string:
        s = v
    default:
        s = "error"
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(GetStatus(uint8(2)), GetStatus("string"), GetStatus(float(42.0)))
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to scale it for more types? Or do I have to write 'case' for every type that I need?

is something like `originalValue := value.(reflect.TypeOf(value))` possible?